# putting a scope into another scope

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

i have the DisplayAlert scope which i want to place in my selectAttraction scope. i want window alert to prompt as well as to get the selected input to display when i click the submit button.

## attraction.js

```
angular
        .module('app')
            .controller('AllAttractionController', ['$scope', 'attraction','$window', function ($scope, attraction, $window) {
                $scope.attractions = attraction.find();



                $scope.imgpath=function(imgName){
                return "../img/"+ imgName;
            };

                $scope.selectAttraction = function()
                {
                    var selected = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i < attractions.length; i++) {
                        if(attraction[i].selected){
                                selected += attraction[i].attractionName;
                        }

                    }

                };
                $scope.DisplayAlert = function(message){
                    $window.alert(message);
                };


            }]);
```

## all-attraction.html

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="selectAttraction('Test')" ui-sref="view-attraction">
```

Comment: So just call `$scope.DisplayAlert()`?

Comment: just add the DisplayAlert inside the ng-click together with the selectAttraction? @dfsq

Comment: Of course you can do it `ng-click="selectAttraction('Test'); DisplayAlert('Booom')"`. Not sure what exactly you need though.

Comment: okay thank you! @dfsq